# Map terrain generation to texture instead of color

Tags: xna, c#, terrain-rendering

I have some terrain being generated using the following algorithm

```
double rand1 = rand.NextDouble() + 1;
double rand2 = rand.NextDouble() + 2;
double rand3 = rand.NextDouble() + 3;

float offset = screenHeight / 2;
//does what it says.
float peakheight = 30;
//really just adjusts the amount of "waves" in the generation
float flatness = 70;

for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++)
{
    double height = peakheight / rand1 * Math.Cos((float)x / flatness * rand1 + rand1);
    height += peakheight / rand2 * Math.Cos((float)x / flatness * rand2 + rand2);
    height += peakheight / rand3 * Math.Cos((float)x / flatness * rand3 + rand3);
    height += offset;
    terrainContour[x] = (int)height;
```

Now to display the "terrain" on the screen I use this block of code to color it

```
Color[] foregroundColors = new Color[screenWidth * screenHeight];

for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++)
    {
        if (y > terrainContour[x])
            foregroundColors[x + y * screenWidth] = Color.Black;
        else
            foregroundColors[x + y * screenWidth] = Color.Transparent;
    }
}

foregroundTexture = new Texture2D(device, screenWidth, screenHeight, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
foregroundTexture.SetData(foregroundColors);
```

Is it possible to set a texture to draw the terrain instead of the `Color.Black` property?
If I had a square texture and I used it to draw the terrain then it would look somewhat blocky and I would then be able to further implement collisions easier.

Comment: Do you actually mean texture? I'm not sure how a texture would make it easier to implement collisions. Do you actually want to change the terrain shape?

Comment: The idea is to use a square texture (like a pixel) and generate the terrain with that instead of a Color. I thought that if I used a square texture to generate the terrain, it would appear in a blocky shape, like [Terraria terrain] (http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/images/11/june/terr/terr8.jpg), However I'm not entirely sure how I could implement it.

Comment: See these links: http://accidentalnoise.sourceforge.net/minecraftworlds.html http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14238/what-is-a-good-technique-for-2d-tile-based-terrain-generation-meeting-these-requ http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/ http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15573/heightmap-voxel-polygon-geometry-terrains

Comment: These are great, but it doesn't have much to do with what I'm trying to do...

Comment: Sure it does. It's about taking noise and generating terrain. I think your idea of creating a texture that just has squares on it won't work very well. More research would be good for you at the moment.